# Erlang: multiply two lists

Tags: list, erlang

I would like to multiply two lists, all values to all.

```
list:seq(1, 100) * list:seq(1, 100)
```

Could you, please, help me to manage it?

Comment: What should be result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean by *multiply two lists*?

```
L1 = L2 = lists:seq(1, 100),
[ X * Y || X <- L1, Y <- L2 ].
```

or

```
[ X * Y || {X, Y} <- lists:zip(L1, L2) ].
```

or

```
[ [ X * Y || Y <- L2 ] || X <- L1 ].
```

or

```
[ lists:duplicate(X, L2) || X <- L1 ].
```

or ... you name it.

Comment: Thanks, the first one is what I meant

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ: Well, it is called cartesian product.